# How to load kernel module in Chromium OS?

Tags: usb, wifi, kernel-modules, chrome-os

I've installed the Chromium Vanilla by Hexxeh to a USB drive, but I can't use it on my computer because it lacks the carl9170 driver, which is needed by my adapter (a D-Link DWA-160.)

I've managed to get it booted on the Netbook, whose wireless chip is supported, and I've downloaded carl9170-1.fw version 1.9.7 for Linux kernel 3.1 and higher (the version of Chromium OS I have uses 3.0.4.)

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to get the driver loaded. I've tried putting it in all kinds of locations, and I've made lots of different attempts to load it with both `modprobe` and `insmod`, but I can't seem to figure out what to do. `modprobe` usually complains about "module not found".

Comment: A firmware file is sometimes needed for a kernel module, but it is not the actual kernel module.

Comment: @jordanm Okay, where might I find the kernel module needed? It (my Wi-Fi adapter) is recognized by `lspci`, does that mean anything?

Comment: Do you have source code for the carl9170?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude it's part of the upstream kernel. You will need to compile it for that exact kernel version.

Comment: @ymn Yeah, carl9170 is open-source, but I always have terrible luck compiling code, PLUS the version numbers of my "normal use" computer and the Chrome OS's kernels are different.

Comment: @jordanm Okay, I have kernel version 3.2.0 on my computer, the Chrome OS has version 3.0.4. Can I still compile it?

Comment: Wait... I just realized that I can't find the *driver* anywhere, only the firmware. I also don't know whether the driver itself is open-source, or just the firmware.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=DWA-160+linux → http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/229-ubuntu-precise-dlink-dwa160-revb2 → http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5032

Comment: Okay, I got `rt2870.bin` and `carl9170-1.fw` copied to `/lib/firmware/`, will reply back with results.

Comment: okay, no luck with `insmod /lib/firmware/rt2870.bin`, it says "-1 invalid module format." Same result with `insmod /lib/firmware/carl9170-1.fw`, and `modprobe carl9170` still returns "FATAL: Module carl9170 not found."