# Chromium OS says "Your system is repairing itself. Please wait" and then reboots

Tags: live-usb, reboot, chrome-os, chromium-os

I downloaded ChromeOS-Vanilla-3851.0.2013_03_17_1641-r7af8fe3d.zip from chromeos.hexxeh.net, then extracted and "burned" to a 4GB USB drive with `dd if=ChromeOS-Vanilla-3851.0.2013_03_17_1641-r7af8fe3d.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M`.
I can *boot* it on my main computer, a Dell OptiPlex GX620, but I can't use it due to connectivity problems (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68012/how-to-load-kernel-module-in-chromium-os) if you want to help.) I can, however, get it booted and working on the Netbook, which is a Toshiba NB255.

I recently got a Laptop, it has no battery, and when trying to boot Chromium OS on it, it says "Your system is repairing itself. Please wait." and then reboots. I let it keep cycling for literally an hour, then decided that it was, in fact, *not* actually repairing anything. What am I doing wrong? The laptop is a Dell Inspiron B130.